# Can one snap part rely on another at the build step?

Tags: snap

Is there any way to have a part depend on other parts in its build step? I know you can specify ordering with **after** but that doesn't seem to work.

The dependency in question is a python package that is needed by another package's install_requires group; it builds fine as a separate part but once built the main package's part can't seem to find the library and needs it to build. I can come up with workarounds, but was wondering if this was at all possible.

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific and post details.

Comment: It's not part of e.g. a requirements.txt? Have you tried simply specifying it with `python-packages`?